# importing fs inside a next.js serverless function gives error

Tags: next.js, serverless

In Next.js 14 I'm trying to import 'fs'  inside a serverless function:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from 'path';


export async function POST(req: Request) {

  const promptTemplate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(),"../../src/prompt.txt"), "utf8");
  console.log("promptTemplate", promptTemplate);
  ...
}
```

but the compiler complains with an error:  `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`

I expected no errors

Answer (score 1):

If your filesystem operation allows it, (they don’t all allow this in a serverless environment), try using fs.Promise, e.g. in  javascript:
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

```
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const promptTemplate = await fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), "../../src/prompt.txt"), "utf8");
  console.log("promptTemplate", promptTemplate);
  // ...
}
```

For a small file changing infrequently, you could try embedding it directly in your code as a string literal. Not the best practice, but if it will never change…
So, in javascript:

```
const promptTemplate = `
  Your file content here
`;
```